# Inserting a string into the middle of a TXT file with PHP

Tags: php, text, insert

There are a few threads about this, but I couldn't find any that deal with inserting text into an unordered text file, after a specified(unique) point, without modifying any of the rest of the file(I apologize if I missed it).

My code, as it stands, seems to work:

```
if($file=fopen('dadada.txt','r+'))
{
echo 'File opened';
$switch=0; //This variable will indicate whether the string has has been found.
$back=0; //This counts the number of characters to move back after reaching eof.
}
while(!feof($file))
{
$string=fgets($file);
if($switch==1)
{
$back+=strlen($string);
$modstring=$modstring.$string;
}
if(strpos($string,'thing to find')!==FALSE)
{
echo 'String found';
$switch=1;
$string=fgets($file);
$modstring='test'.$string;
$back+=strlen($string);
}
}
$back*=-1;
fseek($file,$back,SEEK_END);
fwrite($file,$modstring);
fclose($file);
?>
```

But this seems pretty inelegant, particularly the switch variable to begin recording the contents of the file. I assume there is a much better way to do this than my solution. Is there?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode the file by new line.

That will give you a nice array with each line.

Loop through and find the point of insertion and add the text you want to add.

Then implode it back and write it to the file back.

Comment: I didn't even think of exploding the whole file by new line, but line breaks are the one thing that orders the text. That is a much better idea than my code. Thank you.

Comment: PHP can only read write and append to a text file. If you want to add a text anywhere else then the end you have to read it in a variable, modify the variable and write it back. To make things simpler it's usually a good parctice to explode by new line. \r\n, \r or \n depending on the file's line ending type.