# How do i make php write <div> tags on each side of some content that gets submitted from a form?

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I'm trying to get PHP to write  tags on each side of content that gets submitted from a form in order to format it through css. I have tried preg_replace, but im not sure im using it right. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Found the solution to the problem! For anyone who wonders, i used str_replace

```
$newline.='</li>';
}

else{
    $newline.=$line;   // legger til melding i tillegg til hva som ligger fra før
    $div = array($newline);
    $tagger = array('<li class="innlegg">'.$newline);
}
}

$newline2 = str_replace($div, $tagger, $newline);
```

The script i have going looks like this:

```
$sidet = $_POST['sidet']; 
$melding = $_POST['Melding']; 
$insertPos=0;  




$file=fopen("htmltest.html","r+") or exit("Error occurd"); 

while (!feof($file)) { 
$line=fgets($file);

if (strpos($line, '<body>')!==false) {
$insertPos=ftell($file);    
$newline = $melding;
}

else{
$newline.=$line;   
}

}


fseek($file,$insertPos);  
fwrite($file,$str);



fclose($file); 

echo "Your submission is recieved and will be posted as soon as possible";

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$content = '<div>' . $content . '</div>';`?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103593/using-php-how-to-insert-text-without-overwriting-to-the-beginning-of-a-text-fil

Comment: @Sammitch Sadly it didnt work. Are you sure PHP lets you define variables that way? If so, my solution shouldnt by far away :) 

Edit: When i tried it out, the code only wrote <div> to the file, not the content with div tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
$melding = '<div class="whatever">'.$melding.'</div>';
```