# how to write a file in php without getting it overwritten

Tags: php

My code is generating some problems.The previous content of the file is getting overwrited

```
       <?php
       $g=fopen("lop.txt","r");
       $m=fgets($g);
       echo $m;
       fclose($g);
       $j="tendoeschate";
       $b=fopen("lop.txt","w");
       $p=fwrite($b,$j);
       $t=fgets($b);
       echo $t;
       ?>
```

in this my previous content is getting overwrited when i am appending new content please help

Comment: So open it in append mode (`a`) rather than simple write (`w`) and READ THE [DOCS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) IN FUTURE

Comment: http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103593/using-php-how-to-insert-text-without-overwriting-to-the-beginning-of-a-text-fil

Answer (score 1):

replace fwrite by :

```
file_put_contents("lop.txt", $j, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open file using correct mode. Just look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Instead of w mode you should use a mode to append content to the end of file

Answer (score 0):

You can always grab the contents of the old file and then combining that string with your new content string, then write that complete line.

```
$existingData = file_get_contents($file);
$newData = "Blablabla";
$totalData = $existingData.'. '.$newData;

fwrite($file, $totalData);
```

You can also turn `$totalData` around so it writes newer data in front of old data. Still, using `FILE_APPEND` is more efficient though.